# Calculate $\epsilon_1$ given geometry and capacitance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, dielectric

> The space between two plates in a capacitor is filled with a material
>   with permittivity that varies according to
>
> $$\epsilon(x)=\frac{\epsilon_0}{1+\frac{\epsilon_1}{3d^2}x^2}, \tag1$$
>
> where $x$ is the distance from the lower plate, $d$ is the distance
>   between the plates and the area is $S$. Given that the capacitance is
>   $C$, determine $\epsilon_1$.

[image]

In the solution for this problem they start by setting $\mathbf{D}=D\hat{x}$ so $\mathbf{E}=\mathbf{D}/\epsilon(x).$ Then they say that

$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{D}=\rho=0\implies\frac{\partial D}{\partial x}=0\implies D=\text{constant}. \tag2$$

The constant $k$ is now given by the boundary conditions for the $\mathbf{D}$ field: $$\mathbf{D}_{1n}-\mathbf{D}_{2n}=\rho_s \implies \mathbf{D}_{1n}=D, \ \mathbf{D}_{2n}=0, \ \rho_s=\frac{q}{S} \implies D=-\frac{q}{S}.\tag3$$

This gives us $\mathbf{E}=-\frac{q}{S\epsilon(x)} \ \hat{x}.$

From here on things are straight forward. Get $\Delta V$ by integrating $\mathbf{E}$ from $0$ to $d$ and finally set $C=q/\Delta V$ and solve for $\epsilon_1.$

I just need some steps here explained.

1. In (2), the formula in m,y book is $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{D}=\rho_{\text{free}}$. Why are my free charges $0$ in this example, why don't they exist?
2. I don't understand the math behind (3). Which of the normal components are given? I do understand that $\rho_s=q/S$ but in (2) they got that $D=k$, is this the magnitude of $\mathbf{D}_{1n}$ or $\mathbf{D}_{2n}$?

I haven't really gotten the hang of how to use the boundary conditions in problem solving.